# How to make a "Typical" and "Custom" installation option in Inno Setup?

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I've seen a lot of software give users an option to install software with the typical settings, or to allow the users to choose what settings they prefer (like whether they want a desktop icon or not). How can I do this with Inno Setup?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a sample of doing just this with the Inno Setup install. See the Inno Setup 5\Examples\Components.iss file that comes with Inno Setup itself.

The example shows creating "Full", "Compact", and "Custom" installation options in a single Setup.exe file.

```
; -- Components.iss --
; Demonstrates a components-based installation.

; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING .ISS SCRIPT FILES!

[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
DefaultGroupName=My Program
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\MyProg.exe
OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output

[Types]
Name: "full"; Description: "Full installation"
Name: "compact"; Description: "Compact installation"
Name: "custom"; Description: "Custom installation"; Flags: iscustom

[Components]
Name: "program"; Description: "Program Files"; Types: full compact custom; Flags: fixed
Name: "help"; Description: "Help File"; Types: full
Name: "readme"; Description: "Readme File"; Types: full
Name: "readme\en"; Description: "English"; Flags: exclusive
Name: "readme\de"; Description: "German"; Flags: exclusive

[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: program
Source: "MyProg.chm"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: help
Source: "Readme.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: readme\en; Flags: isreadme
Source: "Readme-German.txt"; DestName: "Liesmich.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: readme\de; Flags: isreadme

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\My Program"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the `[Code]` Section

The answer given by Ken White ***only*** works with Files to include/exclude from the installation.

It does not disable the dir page or the page that asks the user, if he wants or not the desktop icon. *(for example)*

Check out the example : **`CodeClasses.iss`** within `C:\Program Files\Inno Setup 5\Examples`

Comment: No one mentioned disabling dir. page. The OP asked how to make setup that will *"allow the users to choose what settings they prefer (like whether they want a desktop icon or not)."* And that's exactly what Ken showed in his answer. Besides, you don't need to use `[Code]` section to disable dir. page.

Comment: if you want the page to be disabled if the user clicked a button 'standard installation' ? And I don't think Ken showed how to disable the desktop icon creation with types/components..

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean. You are thinking of the installation type option offered somewhere at the beginning of the setup (something [`like this`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BUM3R.png)). Well, the question doesn't sound like the OP wanted that.

Comment: "with the typical settings, or to allow the users to choose " I guess that's it, or I'm wrong :p

Comment: Well, you are both right, just looking at the question from a different perspective. You wanted some sort of *after welcome* buttons offering the type of installation, whilst the OP probably a combo box with setup types which selects corresponding components.